# Getting error when running pre-commit run

Tags: python, git, hook, pre-commit, pre-commit.com

I have installed and configured pre-commit. When running `pre-commit run` I get this INFO followed by an error message:

```
[INFO] Initializing environment for C:\Users\username\projectname.
[INFO] Installing environment for C:\Users\username\projectname.
[INFO] Once installed this environment will be reused.
[INFO] This may take a few minutes... 
An unexpected error has occurred: CalledProcessError: Command: ('C:\Users\username\.cache\pre-commit\repo1qx9mnkz\py_env-python3.7\Scripts\pip.exe', 'install', '.') ERROR: Directory '.' is not installable. Neither 'setup.py' nor 'pyproject.toml' found.
```

I am running it from Windows, using anaconda bash. I put git on the path so that pre-commit finds the repo.
I have already tried to run it from outside anaconda environment but even deactivating it and installing pre-commit again, the error persists.
I have tried also to run `pre-commit clean` , which has worked to solve a previous problem (it could not find at first my "pre-commit-hooks.yaml" file") , but this error persists.

Comment: This is my pre-commit-config.yaml code:
repos:
-   repo: C:\Users\username\projectname
    rev: dev
    hooks:
    -   id: hookname
        language: python

Comment: Hard to say without looking at the directory structure and the list of files. Where is `setup.py`?

Comment: this isn't answerable without seeing the contents of your `.pre-commit-config.yaml` (and your `.pre-commit-hooks.yaml`).  From what you've given it sounds like you're trying to write your own hooks, you might find the docs useful: https://pre-commit.com/#new-hooks (and for python: https://pre-commit.com/#python)